Installing `uprml-h` font?
I have an old document containing some Japanese text that was written to use uplatex and dvipdfmx.  I have both of those installed from TeXLive, and uplatex works, but dvipdfmx fails with these messages:
$ dvipdfmx Japanese.dvi
Japanese.dvi -> Japanese.pdf
[1
dvipdfmx:warning: Unparsed material at end of special ignored.

Current input buffer is -->concordance:Japanese.tex:/Users/murdoch/temp/patch...<--

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+231/600 --dpi 831 uprml-h
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for uprml-h.
mktexpk: perhaps uprml-h is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

dvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "uprml-h".
dvipdfmx:warning: >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font.
dvipdfmx:warning: >> Font file name "uprml-h" was assumed but failed to locate that font.
dvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

No output PDF file written.

I think the warning about the unparsed material isn't serious, but the inability to make the uprml-h font is stopping things from working.  I've tried guessing at what package to install using tlmgr, but can't find the right one.
How do I install the appropriate font to get this to work?
EDITED to add:
I have made some progress. The font I want appears to be available on this Github site:  https://github.com/texjporg/uptex-fonts .  I cloned that site, and ran make; make install, and it appears the font was installed, but it still isn't seen by dvipdfmx.  Presumably I need to do something more, but what?
Additional edit:
As suggested in the comments, I installed the TeXLive package haranoaji.  Something is still missing in my installation, because
even a minimal document like this J.tex shows problems:
\documentclass[12pt]{ujarticle}

\title{Sample document}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

When I run
uplatex J.tex
dvipdfmx J

I get these messages:
J.dvi -> J.pdf
[1
dvipdfmx:warning: Could not read encoding file: UniJIS2004-UTF16-H
dvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "uprml-h".
dvipdfmx:warning: >> This font is mapped to a physical font "HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf".
dvipdfmx:warning: >> Please check if kpathsea library can find this font: HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf
dvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

No output PDF file written.

I haven't followed the advice about kpathsea, because I don't know how.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

The fonts are in TeX Live. Can you please add a small example of a document that shows the issue?

Did you try to install the TeX Live package haranoaji?

@egreg:  just did, and it has changed things, but not solved my problems.  See my edit to the question.

I asked about this on the uptex-fonts project on Github, and got this advice that solved my problem:  run tlmgr install collection-langjapanese.  That provided everything I needed.
